# Retrofit FormUrlEncoded requests not working with Array of objects as Field

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Guys i have an api that accepts inputs in the form

```
[{"username":"usr","password":"123456","userflag":"1"}]
```

and i wrote a Retrofit Service as

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    fun login(  @Field("login") List<LoginModel>): Call<Any>
```

and the LoginModel is

```
data class LoginModel(
        @SerializedName("username") var username:String,
        @SerializedName("password") var password:String,
        @SerializedName("userflag") var userflag:String
        )
```

When i call the api by passing parameters as List
the server gives 500 error as it wont recive the parameters.

But the same thing works when i use JsonArray Instead of List<> as

```
json.addProperty("username", loginModel.username)
        json.addProperty("userflag", loginModel.userflag)
        json.addProperty("password", loginModel.password)

        var jarray = JsonArray()
        jarray.add(json)

    var call: Call<Any> = GetDataService.create().login(jarray.toString())
```

along with

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
fun login(  @Field("login") data:String): Call<Any>
```

Why the same refuse to work with a List as parameter..??

Comment: Instead of `@Field` it should be `@Body`

Comment: the key "login" should be passed.. "login":[{"username":"usr","password":"123456","userflag":"1"}]  is the requirement. 
 @Body doesnot accept keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i couldn't find a proper solution. I continued to use it by converting model to string using Gson.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
fun login(  @Field("login") data:String): Call<Any>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and send the array of **LoginModel**:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("login")
        fun login(  @Field("login") LoginModel[]): Call<Any>
```

Comment: Sorry bro. its looks like a syntactically error.  passing LoginModel[ ] shows error